# Get the operation count added in Nest.BulkDescriptor according to type of bulk operations

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I require to get operation count inside BulkDescriptor object that was created for Bulk operation in NEST. Correctly their to no option to get the same information.

e.g

```
 BulkDescriptor bulkDescriptor = new BulkDescriptor();
 bulkDescriptor.Index<my_objects>(op => op.Document(pObj).Index(elasticsearchIndexName).Type("my_objects_document"));
```

after addding an document to be indexed I need to get the count of my Indexed Operation before I call

```
Nest.ElasticClient elasClient = new Nest.ElasticClient(elasticConn);
IBulkResponse ibulkResp = elasClient.Bulk(bulkDescriptor);
```

Thanks,
amal

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get count of operations just like this:

```
var count = (bulkDescriptor as IBulkRequest).Operations.Count;
```

Comment: Hi, an old one, but how would you get the size in Bytes of the request?

Comment: You can access request byte array from NEST response, but how depends which version of NEST do you use.